# Django 1.6 Issue when trying to add fields to User Object with AbstractUser

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a couple of fields to the user model in Django 1.6. I rather add them directly to User object rather than make a profile. However, I am having the following issues:

models.py:

```
class Employee(AbstractUser):
    emp_irc_name = models.CharField(max_length="25")
    emp_forum_username = models.CharField(max_length="25")
```

Error output:

```
(bot)one@chat-dash /home/git/bot_server/bot_server $ python manage.py syncdb
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
bot_data.employee: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
bot_data.employee: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.

(bot)one@chat-dash /home/git/bot_server/bot_server $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Django not to create the standard auth.User model. You do that by specifying [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) in settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'bot_data.Employee'
```